# query unidirectional many2one index

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to make Hibernate Search index the following relationship:

DocVersion *<-> Document2 -> DocType

```
@Indexed
@Entity
public class Document2 implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "doc_uuid")
    private long id;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "documentType")
    private DocType docType;
}



@Indexed
@Entity
public class DocType implements  Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "doctype_id")
    private long id;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "documentType")
    private String documentType;
}
```

so it's unidiretcional `@ManyToOne` relation from the Document2 class because `DocType` is only a codetable.

However I need to query index based on cdt's property like `document2.docType.documentType` which gives me:

```
WARNING: org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: Unable to find field document2.docType.documentType in com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocVersion
```

what am I missing?

hibernate-search: 5.9.3.Final

Comment: Please give us the code for `DocVersion`, the full stack trace, and the code used to build and execute your query.

Comment: yeeah, it's all pretty casual, but I found the problem. will post
this is all stacktrace I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have missed `@ContainedIn` that needs to be on the opposite side of the `@IndexedEmbedded`. For me in `Document2`:

```
    @ContainedIn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "document2", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(
            usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE
    )
    private Set<DocVersion> docVersions;
```

and in the `DocType` as a 'leaf' doesn't need to have link back to `Document2` at all.

Hope that helps someone